# How to get a valid iterator after string replacement

Tags: c++, string, replace, iterator, invalidation

I want to do some string replacement in C++ under Windows using iterators.
This is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

size_t iterator_to_size_t(std::string &string, std::string::iterator it)
{
    size_t pos;
    pos = std::distance(string.begin(), it);
    return pos;
}


int main()
{
    std::string text = "TTTTbcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    std::string findtext = "TTTT";
    std::string replacementtext = "123456";

    for (std::string::iterator it = text.begin(); it!=text.end(); ++it)
    {
        size_t z = iterator_to_int(text, it);
        if (text.compare(z, findtext.length(), findtext) == 0)
        {
            text.replace(z, findtext.length(), replacementtext);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The string::replace method obviously invalidates the iterator. I get an error message saying that. I have tried to assign the return value of string::replace to the iterator it to get a new valid iterator, but the return value seems not to be compatible.

How can I get a valid iterator here or do I have to use indices instead of iterators?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values instead of default-initializing them and immediately assigning new values. That is, change `size_t pos; pos = ...;` to `size_t pos = ...;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can recalculate the iterator after a replacement, e.g.

```
if (text.compare(z, findtext.length(), findtext) == 0)
{
    text.replace(z, findtext.length(), replacementtext);
    it = text.begin() + z + replacementtext.size();
}
```

Besides, having a loop that uses iterators, computing a position index from those iterators and using the position index to get an iterator back is really cumbersome. I would advise you to consider the following.

```
#include <regex>

const std::regex re{"TTTT"};
text = std::regex_replace(text, re, replacementtext);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This code snippet that I posted was meant to be a part for a function that gets the current system time and formats it according to a given format string (also including milliseconds which prevented me from using strftime and the like). I did this with regular expressions, but they seem to slow down the pasring enormousy. That#s why I turned to "standard" string replacement.

Comment: Have you benchmarked how much `<regex>` slowed down the function in comparison to the manual replacement? The standard regex implementation is known to not be the fastest possible, but before switching to something more complicated/error-prone, you should probably profile/benchmark the code?

Comment: I haven't tried the non regex one ,but I tested it with the measure-command command in powershell, and my version ran 40 ms whereas the builtin get-date commandlet in powershell ran only 9 ms. So I suppose it's due to the regexes, but I might be wrong it is due to me having chosen a slow algorithm

Comment: Generally, when talking about performance, sentences starting with 'So I suppose it's due to ..." are wrong. Never suppose; benchmark and check ;)

Comment: You're absolutely right, so I tested a completey different algorithm (traversing through the format string and doing replacements) without any regexes, and it showed not be be any faster than the solution with regexes, so my assumption was obviously wrong, and there's a different reason for the performance, any way, thanks for your hints